# javascript detect # in url

Tags: javascript

My application is an iframe app so when the user changes page they do not automatically get taken to the top. To combat this on page load I call

```
window.location.hash = 'tophash'
```

I have found however on some rare cases I need to take the user to a specific part of the page. So I make a url with #anotherID on the end. Problem is currently they are taken to tophash on page load.

What I need is if there is a hash within the url it does not run `window.location.hash = 'tophash'`

So my question is... how do I detech the presence of a # in the url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying the `hash` property before setting it should do the job.

```
if ((!window.location.hash) || (window.location.hash == "#"))
 window.location.hash = "tophash";
```

Comment: It's not `== null` when it's empty, at least not on Chrome (http://jsbin.com/ecela4). It *should* be an empty string (and is on Chrome: http://jsbin.com/ecela4/2), but I'd probably code defensively and go with `== ""`.

Comment: @T.J. good point! Changed to a `length` check and added a check for a lone `#` just to make sure - Chrome takes away lone `#`es but I wouldn't trust everyone does

Comment: @Starlin argh, my update was humbug, sorry. Please use the one posted now

Comment: !window.location.hash is a better way of checking hash, notice the ! Empty string, array, 0, undefined and null will all evaluate to false when using !

Comment: @BGerrissen fair point! Wasn't aware `!` was this flexible in JS. Changed.

Comment: @BGerrissen - That's not quite accurate. They will technically evaluate to `true` when using `!` because they are all "falsey". I imagine that's what you meant. (Except that *empty array* is not "falsey" like the rest).

Comment: I stand corrected, rather meant 'evaluate to boolean' and yeh, empty array doesn't evaluate to false.